# Magento 2 : "Please Wait" Spinner Shows up Between EVERY Field While New Order in Admin

Tags: magento2, admin, sales-order, create-order

I enter new order in my admin, as I move from field to field (say, customer first name to customer last name) little 'please wait' spinner appears for a second or 2.  This slows order creation process as we have to wait between EVERY field when entering new order.

How can I make this stop?  Is it trying to check shipping rates between every field or something?

Comment: I guess I'm a bit of a noob here, but how is it a good idea to let other people edit my original question / post? The edits done by Dhiren Vasoya (and I guess approved by someone else with whatever karma stackexchange gives to active people) have made my post and question harder to understand and have not made anything clearer.  As the original poster, do I have any power to undo these changes?

Comment: Can anyone shed any light on this?